# How can a copy a date from other variable in R?

Tags: r

Mydata has a date with time.

```
Date:
2008-04-21 11:00:00
NA
NA
2008-04-20 11:00:00
```

`str(Mydata)` said that Date is POSIXct. So I'm trying to create a new variable.

```
myData$Date2 <- ifelse(is.na(Mydata$OtherVariable), NA, Mydata$Date)).
```

I want to create a new variable that is NA if OtherVariable is NA, or exactly Mydata$Date if not.
But Mydata$Date gave me a number like 1.24e+09, maybe does not recognise date POSIXct. I tried as.POSIXct(Mydata$Date) but doesn't work.

Comment: Adding to the answer from Ronak Shah, I think the issue might be that your `NA` comes in with the format from `OtherVariable` and so the new column is no longer `POSIXct`. If you add `as.POSIXct` around the `NA` in your `ifelse` that might fix it, or just type-convert `Date2` after.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `ifelse` use `dplyr::if_else` which is type-strict and will not change the time to numbers.

```
Mydata$Date2 <- dplyr::if_else(is.na(Mydata$OtherVariable), 
                               as.POSIXct(NA, tz = 'UTC'), Mydata$Date)
```

Or another way without using `ifelse` in base R would be :

```
Mydata$Date2 <- as.POSIXct(NA, tz = 'UTC')
inds <- !is.na(Mydata$OtherVariable)
Mydata$Date2[inds] <- Mydata$Date[inds]
```

Comment: I tried with Mydata$Date2 <- dplyr::if_else(is.na(Mydata$OtherVariable), 
                               as.POSIXct(NA), Mydata$Date). It's weird, for example, in Mydata$Date is 2008-04-21 11:35:00 but copy in Mydata$Date2 2008-04-21 08:35:00. In every row, there is a problem with the hour.

Comment: I tried with Mydata$Date2 <- dplyr::if_else(is.na(Mydata$OtherVariable), 
                               as.POSIXct(NA), Mydata$Date). It's weird, for example, in Mydata$Date is 2008-04-21 11:35:00 but copy in Mydata$Date2 2008-04-21 08:35:00. In every row, there is a problem with the hour. Year, month, day, minute and second are good, but the hour is wrong.

Comment: Ohh...that is because `as.POSIXct` takes your local timezone. Try with `as.POSIXct(NA, tz = 'UTC')`